# Python, reading lines from a file one by one

Tags: python

im making a program wich sorts out valid and invalid social security numbers.

The program is supposed to be able to sort numbers from a textfile on my computer. However im only able to input all the numbers at once (i think). i wont the program to check the numbers one by one.

this is how it looks right now

```
def fileinput():
    try:
        textfile = open("numberlist.txt","r")
        socialsecuritynumber = textfile.read()
        numberprogram(socialsecuritynumber)
    except IOError:
        print("there's no such file!\n")
```

anyone know how im supposed to do this?
the textfile just contains numbers

- 1993-06-11 5570
- 930611-5570
- 930611 5570
- 93 05115570
- 1993 05 11 55 70
- 1993 05 11 5570

this is numbers from my textfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("numberlist.txt") as f: # this auto closes the file after reading. It's good practice
    numbers = f.readlines() # numbers is a list of all the numbers(a list of lines in the file)
```

if there are unwanted spaces in the lines(or just in case there are):

```
numbers = [n.strip() for n in numbers] # takes out unwanted spaces on the ends
```

and if you find there are commas or something after the numbers, you can do this:

```
numbers = [n[:-1] for n in numbers] # slices off the last character of each line/list item

for number in numbers:
    #do whatever you want here
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively you could use a regular expression, and commas and spaces won't matter:

```
import re

n = ['1993-06-11 5570',
     '930611-5570',
     '930611 5570',
     '93 05115570',
     '1993 05 11 55 70',
     '1993 05 11 5570']

regex = '([0-9]+(?:[- ]?[0-9]+)*)'
match_nums = [re.search(regex, num) for num in n]
results = [i.groups() for i in match_nums]
for i in results:
    print i

('1993-06-11 5570',)
('930611-5570',)
('930611 5570',)
('93 05115570',)
('1993 05 11 55 70',)
('1993 05 11 5570',)
```

for info on regular expressions, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

Comment: tried that out and its working couse now its checking every line one by one, however it says that all numbers are invalid now, am i getting any thing else then just the integer numbers when im trying to check that? i mean is there some kind och tab or space or something with the numbers?

Comment: actually, if they have commas or something at the ends of the line, that cold be interfering with your validation. Can you show me exactly what the lines look like, or are they always different(sometimes commas, sometimes not, sometimes something else, etc.) Also, if you could provide your validation code that would be good

Comment: the problem is that there are spaces and "-" between the digits and i need them to stay there before the whole line enters my program, tha validation code is quite long but if you got skype or something i could send u there.

Comment: updated the post again to include a possibly better alternative

Comment: ah ye i looked up regular expression when i started but i kinda considered it being a bit to complicated to use though. I dont have enough rep to upvote you yet but i will do when i can!! really awesome help!

could you take a look on another part of my program?

Comment: sure, but if it's a basically a totally different question, maybe you should make another post. Glad I could help!

Comment: ye i made another post now named "python, trying to sort lines from a textfile" if u wanna take a look! :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Always read files with [with](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement. So, if there is a problem during read, or there is an exception in the code block, file will be closed automatically.
2. Then use a for loop to read line by line like this

   ```
   with open("numberlist.txt","r") as textfile:
       for line in textfile:
           print line
   ```

Comment: **EDITED:** *with* intercepts errors within the block - but it will not intercept error within it's line, i.e. it will not intercept error of file not found.

Answer (score 0):

Use with as thefourtheye suggested. You can use the readLines() method and iterate over the lines one by one using a for-in loop and check for the validity. This will ensure that even for large files, your code doesn't break.

Answer (score 0):

Using with for file operations is suggested. If it is Python 2.4 or something, you have to import with statement. Simplest solution for your problem with numbers that I could think of is:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
file_with_ssn = "/absolute/path/to/the/file"

try:
    with open(file_with_ssn) as ssn_file:
        for ssn in ssn_file:
            ssn = filter(str.isdigit, ssn)
            # This removes anything other than a number including -.
            # Since SSN cannot be in negative, isdigit is fine here
            numberprogram(ssn)
except EnvironmentError:
    print "IOError or OSError or WindowsError happened"
```